# 2147483648 and 2147483647, which is the biggest value of integer?

Tags: java, literals, lexical

When I read the Java 13 spec, I saw 2 things as follows:

> 1. The largest decimal literal of type int is 2147483648 (2^31).
> 2. The largest positive hexadecimal, octal, and binary literals of type int - each of which represents the decimal value 2147483647
>      (2^31-1) - are respectively

I don't understand exactly what is the literal. But:

For me, I think when we mention about the "largest decimal **literal** of type int", we just focus on what the int type can show, it means that in terms of lexical/vocabulary, the largest digits sequence available is 2^31.

This also means that regardless of negative or positive integer semantically, we cannot write any digits sequence exceeded 2^31 (e.g 2^31 + 1).

Although "literal" can have many meanings, in this case, I think that it just refers to lexical terms.

So, my explanation is correct or incorrect? Anyone can help me, please.

Thank you

Comment: You might want to learn about [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) which is by far the most common way to represent signed integers in a binary system.

Comment: Maybe the minus sign got lost...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thank you. But my question is in this case, the concept "literal" just refers to lexical/vocabulary structure (it means: what we can type to express the integer)?

Comment: "Literal" here just means that you specify the value of the number directly in Java source code, as in `int i = 12345;`. It is one type of token in the syntax for Java (another one would be the `i` which is an identifier). You can have String literals (like `"foo"`), or numeric literals for things like `int`, `long`, `double`. And integer literals don't have to be given as decimal, you can write things like `0xFF` or the always confusing `012` (which is octal for ten).

Comment: The first means the counting which includes 0 hence  2147483648. The second means in hex and the max in hex is 0x7FFFFFFF (because the last bit is used as sign: 1 for minus, 0 for plus) hence 2147483647

Comment: *"my question is in this case, the concept "literal" just refers to lexical/vocabulary structure"*, yes

Comment: JLS [3.10. Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10) says: A *literal* is the **source code representation of a value** of a primitive type ([§4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)), the String type ([§4.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.3)), or the null type ([§4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1)).